# Hotfixes and release branches

Tags: git-flow

Imagine you are preparing a `release`, and you also have to make a `hotfix`. The docs say, you should merge the `hotfix` branch to `master` and `develop` branches. But what about the `release` branch? I guess I should also merge it here, right? Or should I merge the `hotfix` just to `release` and then `realease` back to `develop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is debated here : https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/177 , conclusion is that hotfix could be merged to the latest release branch with a post-flow-hotfix-finish hook.